# Early 90's cartoon about weapons made out of a special metal

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember very little about this cartoon, but I will list the elements that I do remember.

The metal was either made from a meteor, or is was an alloy that was made via special techniques.

There was a female character that had shurikens made out of this special metal (she may or may not have worked in a circus).

The premise of the show appeared to be travelling around looking for people that have weapons made out of this metal (I guess no-one thought to make a bicycle or a pen or something out of the stuff).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is "[Conan the Adventurer](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/ConanTheAdventurer)" from 1992.

> *One day, a strange celestial event results in a great shower of
>   shooting stars; while they hit all over the world, several of them
>   land at Conan's mountain, whereupon Conan's father forges the
>   "starmetal" they contain into weapons and makes a profitable business
>   selling them, saving one piece, a mighty broadsword, for Conan.*
>
> ....
>
> *And thus the journey begins... As Conan proceeds to wander the earth
>   and battle Wrath-amon's evil, he makes numberous other allies,
>   including the Vanirman Snagg, the [shuriken-tossing [circus] acrobat Jezmine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJd0-GZrjfE),
>   the warrior-wizard prince of the Wasai Zula, the wind-magician
>   Greywolf, and the winged whip-wielding warrior Falkenar.*

Comment: Whatever.  I've given up trying to figure out how you do it.  I have come to terms with the fact that you, in fact, know everything.

Comment: @MagikarpMaster - I remember watching this

Comment: @Magikarpmaster I agree. In fact, Valorum is one of the reasons I come daily to this site. I enjoy reading all his posts.